# Magento 1 How are div classes generated?

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, select

I have this output in couple product pages:

```
<div class="input-box">
    <select name="options[82]" id="select_82" class=" required-entry 
    product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"> 
    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option><option value="236" 
    price="0">3 Months </option><option value="237" price="50.5284">6 Months 
    +51€</option><option value="238" price="151.5852">12 Months 
    +152€</option></select>
</div>
```

But it should be this:

```
<div class="selectbox">
```

Went through templates, haven't found right place. Maybe it is being rendered by product option type or something else, if so where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out where elements of your Magento site come from by enabling the Hints developer options.

Go to System -> Configuration, scroll down to Developer (Under Advanced) and enable Template Path Hints and (if needed) Add Block Names to Hints.